# Is it possible to show title when clicking on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like title (not Tooltip) to "popup" when the user clicks with the mouse on the div.

I don't want to wait for the title to show up when mouse over (but it also needs to be a mouse over).

```
<div id="someDiv" title ="Info on both click and hover!"></div>
```

At this point I don't care how its done :-)

**EDIT**

Ok to **recap** what I´m trying to do:

**I need to popup the title as soon as I click on the  div, *but if I don´t click* on the div , I like the title to work just as normally with mouseover. There should never be 2 titles showing at once.**

This is just one of the things I tried to solve this. I have the title attribute.. but what now? This is probably something very easy...

```
$('#someDiv').click(function () {
  $(this).attr("title");   
  //And how do I show the title right away?
});
```

Comment: Have you at least tried to do this yourself? Note that StackOverflow is not PeoplePerHour.

Comment: "I don't want to wait for the title to show up when mouse over (but it also needs to be a mouse over)" confusing, where is your code?

Comment: O yes I have tried just about everything to get this to work... StackOverflow question is always my last option!

Comment: @atmd What I mean is that the user should be able to hover over the div and get the title BUT also he should be able to get the title by clicking the div.

Comment: Ok, I see, can you show your code?

Comment: @atmd thats it.. nothing has worked so far... I can add a on click on the div but then what? Find the title tag and then what? How to "pop it up"? I´l edit the question.

Comment: You've said you've tried everything, but the code you have is only html, no javascript. So in order to help we'd need to see what you have so far. You'll be more likley to get answeres with "I have this but it isnt working" rather then asking people to just do it for you from scratch

Answer (score 2):

I created a jQuery function **$.hasTitle()**

This new function take the parent *div.title* of your element and take the next *span.text* to work as a title. Check live:

http://jsfiddle.net/t7kf6ge8/1/

---

js:

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.extend({
        hasTitle: function(){
            $(this).on("mouseenter mouseout", function(e){
                var title = $(this).closest("div.title");
                var text = title.next("span.text").first();
                text.fadeToggle().css({
                    left: e.pageX,
                    top:  e.pageY
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);



$("#elementOne").hasTitle();
$("#elementTwo").hasTitle();
```

---

html:

```
<div class="title">
    <div id="elementOne">
        elementOne
    </div>
</div><span class="text">Title: Info on hover!</span>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="title">
    <ul id="elementTwo">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div><span class="text">It is a list</span>
```

---

css: (The css code you can change to your preference, only *position:absolute* is required because of mouse/cursor effect)

```
span.text{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Comic Sans MS;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

---

Comment: No sorry. I need the title to pop up right away when I click on the  div but if I don´t click on the div I like the title to work just as normal with mouseover.

Comment: That was what I was trying to avoid. I mention that in my question. But probably that is the only way if nobody has an suggestion for a possible solution.

Comment: Ok... I tried a bit more hard and got this now... Check if it helps